# a question about non-finite verbs

Tags: grammar, tenses, nonfinite-verbs

A harmonious society is like a symphony or orchestra—each person contributes a small sound, but when_________ with other sounds, it becomes beautiful music.
A. combining B. being combined C.combined D. to be combined

The correct answer to this question is C. I wonder why I can’t choose B.

In short, what’s the difference between ‘being done’ and ‘done’.

Comment: *Being combined* is a continuous tense, while *combined* isn't necessarily continuous. So it's not grammar but meaning that makes the right choice C rather than B.

Comment: A, B, and C are all grammatical and thus correct, and you absolutely can choose any of them. Selecting which among them is likely to be arbitrarily designated "correct" by the writers and/or scorers of a multiple-choice test is a matter of testmanship, not mastery of English; and that, as often, may involve setting aside one's intelligence and trying to think like a mediocrity.

Comment: @Brian Donovan Eloquently put. More a test of social psychology than English. _And this type of question penalises the better educated._

Comment: By far the most salient choice is "combined". The progressive aspectuality of "combining"     is inappropriate, and "to be combined" is flat ungrammatical. (*... when to be combined")

Comment: @BillJ, Said "progressive aspectuality" seems appropriate enough to my conception of how symphonic music works.